# Get categories of queried posts

Tags: categories, query

I queried posts from an array of IDs:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => $ids,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Now I want to display a form with checkboxes for the categories of these queried posts. For example if there are two posts from the category "Drama" I dont want the "Comedy"-Category-Checkbox to be displayed.

The problem: As there is no post__in parameter for get_categories, I have no idea, how I can do this.

```
$catargs = array(
    'post__in' => $ids,
);

$categories = get_categories(  $catargs  ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a:

1. array of post id ( ok )
2. array of category id ( not yet )
3. array of category id/name with unique value ( not yet )

using `wp_get_posts_categories( $post_id );` returns an array of category id, so you can loop your $ids calling this function to collect all categories id.

with the array of categories id you can set up a brand new one with id/name pair and then with `array_unique();` clean up it from duplicated values.

I can't find any other solution, so:

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
/*
 *Loop through your $ids and:
 * get all the categories id for your queried posts ( wp_get_post_categories( $id ) )
 * loop through this new array to get single category data ( get_category( $catid ) )
 * set up a new array with term_id/name value pairs ( $categories )
 * clean up your new array from duplicate values ( array_unique( $categories ) )
 */
foreach( $ids as $id ){
$catids = wp_get_post_categories( $id );
  foreach( $catids as $catid ){
    $category = get_category( $catid );
    $categories[$category->term_id] = $category->name; 
  }
}

$filtered_categories = array_unique($categories);

?>
```

I've tested and now works. Hope it helps!